# Is an Ultegra front derailleur compatible with Sora shifters?

Tags: derailleur, compatibility, front

I have a old trek road bike with 2X9 setup. I need to change the front derailleur. Can I use a Ultegra fd-r8000?

My shifters is Shimano Sora.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Shimano compatibility chart, a Sora shifter would not be compatible with the Ultegra FD-R8000 front derailleur.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Un*officially, I suspect that Sora shifters would pull the right amount of cable to actuate a front shift with an R8000 FD. I believe that FDs don't have as many compatibility issues as RDs. The problem with your proposed setup is that the R8000 FD is designed for a narrower chain than the one you have. It may not shift properly as a result. If you can't get a Sora FD, it's possible that you could hunt on eBay for another 9s Shimano FD.

If you are upgrading the bike piecemeal, I would ask again if that's necessary. It is definitely not cost effective to do that, as it will cost more than buying a bike that was originally specced with R8000. You will also have a low-end frame.

Comment: *If you are upgrading the bike piecemeal, I would ask again if that's necessary.*  Well, if I put Lamborghini hubcaps on a Versa, it'll go faster!  ;-)

Comment: The front shifter is a far-less precise area of the transmission than the rear shifter.  I've got an original front triple from a "15 speed" aka a 3x5, and it manages to shift 9 speed chain albeit with some extra clattering.   One needs to develop a tolerance for less-than-perfect when riding anything described as "old"  :)

Comment: Sometimes, manufacturers use the very same frame for a wide range of bikes. You cannot really distinguish a Sora-level frame from a Tiagra-level frame. My gravel bike came with Claris but it could have also be bought with 105 at that time. Bow they sell the same frame with Claris, GRX 400 2x or GRX 600 1x. The wheels also appear to be the same.

Comment: thumbs up to this... any performance bonus from it being ultegra will be far outweighed by it being the wrong cage spacing for the chain. No reason not to just get a 9-speed FD.